# Possible paths of NxN array traversing from (0, 0) to (N, N) in a positive direction only?

Tags: java, algorithm

We have an NxN array. I have got the solution to finding out the number of possible paths moving from (0,0) to (N,N) in a positive direction only. You **can not** move **diagonally** or **backwards**.

And the solution is:

```
private void matrixProblem(int N) {
    System.out.println("Total count is : " + String.valueOf(path((N-1), (N-1))));
}

private int path(int x, int y) {

    System.out.println("x = " + x + " " + "y = " + y);
    if (x < 0 || y < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    return path(x - 1, y) + path(x, y - 1);
}
```

But **I also want to print all the possible paths.** 
Like for 3x3 array one possible path is: 
(0,0) --> (1,0) --> (2,0) --> (2,1) --> (2,2)

There are 6 possible paths for 3x3 array. This is one example.

Kindly suggest the best possible way for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to print all the paths, you'll need to pass around your history. This means:

- at every point, add the current entry,
- call your function recursively,
- remove the last entry again.

Alternatively, you could

- at every point, make a copy of the history so far,
- add the current entry to the copy,
- call your function recursively with the copy,

but the former takes less memory and time. This works:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public final class MatrixProblem {

  private final int mx;
  private final int my;

  public MatrixProblem(int N) {
    mx = N;
    my = N;
  }

  public int countAndPrint() {
    return numPathsTracing(0, 0, new ArrayList<>());
  }

  private int numPathsTracing(int x, int y, ArrayList<String> path) {
    if(x > mx || y > my)
      return 0;
    else if(x == mx && y == my) {
      StringBuilder pathString = new StringBuilder();
      for(String previous : path) {
        pathString.append(previous);
        pathString.append(" -> ");
      }
      pathString.append(pathElement(x, y));
      System.out.println(pathString);
      return 1;
    } else {
      path.add(pathElement(x, y));
      int ret = numPathsTracing(x+1, y, path) + numPathsTracing(x, y+1, path);
      path.remove(path.size() - 1);
      return ret;
    }
  }

  private static String pathElement(int x, int y) {
    return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
  }
}
```

Call as:

```
int nPaths = new MatrixProblem(3).countAndPrint();
System.out.println("Total count is : " + nPaths);
```

Output:

```
(0, 0) -> (1, 0) -> (2, 0) -> (3, 0) -> (3, 1) -> (3, 2) -> (3, 3)
(0, 0) -> (1, 0) -> (2, 0) -> (2, 1) -> (3, 1) -> (3, 2) -> (3, 3)
(0, 0) -> (1, 0) -> (2, 0) -> (2, 1) -> (2, 2) -> (3, 2) -> (3, 3)
(0, 0) -> (1, 0) -> (2, 0) -> (2, 1) -> (2, 2) -> (2, 3) -> (3, 3)
(0, 0) -> (1, 0) -> (1, 1) -> (2, 1) -> (3, 1) -> (3, 2) -> (3, 3)
(0, 0) -> (1, 0) -> (1, 1) -> (2, 1) -> (2, 2) -> (3, 2) -> (3, 3)
(0, 0) -> (1, 0) -> (1, 1) -> (2, 1) -> (2, 2) -> (2, 3) -> (3, 3)
(0, 0) -> (1, 0) -> (1, 1) -> (1, 2) -> (2, 2) -> (3, 2) -> (3, 3)
(0, 0) -> (1, 0) -> (1, 1) -> (1, 2) -> (2, 2) -> (2, 3) -> (3, 3)
(0, 0) -> (1, 0) -> (1, 1) -> (1, 2) -> (1, 3) -> (2, 3) -> (3, 3)
(0, 0) -> (0, 1) -> (1, 1) -> (2, 1) -> (3, 1) -> (3, 2) -> (3, 3)
(0, 0) -> (0, 1) -> (1, 1) -> (2, 1) -> (2, 2) -> (3, 2) -> (3, 3)
(0, 0) -> (0, 1) -> (1, 1) -> (2, 1) -> (2, 2) -> (2, 3) -> (3, 3)
(0, 0) -> (0, 1) -> (1, 1) -> (1, 2) -> (2, 2) -> (3, 2) -> (3, 3)
(0, 0) -> (0, 1) -> (1, 1) -> (1, 2) -> (2, 2) -> (2, 3) -> (3, 3)
(0, 0) -> (0, 1) -> (1, 1) -> (1, 2) -> (1, 3) -> (2, 3) -> (3, 3)
(0, 0) -> (0, 1) -> (0, 2) -> (1, 2) -> (2, 2) -> (3, 2) -> (3, 3)
(0, 0) -> (0, 1) -> (0, 2) -> (1, 2) -> (2, 2) -> (2, 3) -> (3, 3)
(0, 0) -> (0, 1) -> (0, 2) -> (1, 2) -> (1, 3) -> (2, 3) -> (3, 3)
(0, 0) -> (0, 1) -> (0, 2) -> (0, 3) -> (1, 3) -> (2, 3) -> (3, 3)
Total count is : 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are learning how to use Java, I suggest you take a more object-oriented approach.

1. Create a Location object which holds the x, y location
2. Each possible path will be represented as a `List<Location>`... (or alternatively, extend AbstractList to make your own Path class.)
3. The recursive function takes an additional path argument (`List<Location>`) and returns a list of paths (`List<List<Location>>`)
4. Inside the recursive calls, create new copies of the path argument so the recursive call is modifying its own copy, not a shared copy
5. The two path lists returned by dual recursive calls are combined into a single path list then returned
6. Another method can iterate over the `List<List<Location>>`, printing each one
7. Location should define a `toString` method that prints in the desired format

Comment: What is point #5? How will I merge both the path lists? What would be the combined array? Should I make it as List<List<Location>> ?

Comment: @SatyaveerSingh `return result1.addAll(result2); // List<List<Location>>`

Answer (score 0):

We can use math to calculate the number of the ways. if you are in (0, 0) and you want to go (N, M). You should take M up and N right. So it becomes this question: in a N+M movements, you choose N of them to be right, the rest is the up. So the total number is (N+M)! / (N!*M!)

If you want to print all the ways. You can use dp to do that. But it will cost a lot of memory.